# Inheritance in C++: Error C2011

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to display Tiles of different colors on a screen in C++ through inheritance. I have a base class called Tile and then two derived classes called GreenTile and VanillaTile.

In my main, when I create only a GreenTile or only a VanillaTile by creating either a GreenTile object or a VanillaTile object, it works properly:

```
GreenTile greenTile(0,0);
greenTile.show(screen);
```

The problem is, when I create both GreenTile and VanillaTile objects and try to display both I'm getting "error C2011: 'Tile' : 'class' type redefinition".

```
GreenTile greenTile(0,0);
VanillaTile vanillaTile(0,0);
greenTile.show(screen);
vanillaTile.show(screen);
```

Comment: Show us the header files

Comment: It sounds like you're not using include guards, which have nothing to do with inheritance.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard .

Comment: @AntonGolov you should post your comment as an answer for others to see in case they encounter the same error.

Answer (score 5):

What you are running into has nothing to do with inheritance:  it is a matter of using so-called [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).  Note that these will generally only protect against multiple definition errors issued by the compiler, not by the linker.

Answer (score 4):

In your source code where `main` is (let's say that is `main.cpp`), you probably have

```
#include "GreenTile.h"    // (1)
#include "VanillaTile.h"  // (2)
```

and in each of these headers you have

```
#include "Tile.h"
```

If your `Tile.h` doesn't have include guards you're including twice definiton of the class `Tile`.  Your Tile.h should look like this:

```
#ifndef TILE_H
#define TILE_H

class Tile
{
   ...
};

#endif
```

Preprocessor copies the content of headers (1) and (2) at the beginning of `main.cpp`. With them it copies twice `Tile.h` but because of these guards only content of the first copy remains. This way compiler doesn't complaint as it sees a single definition of class `Tile`.

Answer (score 0):

One could also use #pragma once in this situation. #pragma once has some advantages over the include guards: it contains less code, avoids name clashes and sometimes takes less compile time.